# Find the eigen values and the associated eigen vectors of $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}3&1&1\\2&4&2\\1&1&3\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Sol. det($A-\lambda I$)$=0$ $\implies \lambda = 2, 2, 6.$
 Determining eigen vector with respect to the eigen value $\lambda=2:$
$ \begin{pmatrix}
1~~1~~1\\
2~~2~~2\\
1~~1~~1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$ implies that

$x+y+z=0\\
~~~~~~x+y+z=0\\
~~~~~~x+y+z=0$.
Solving this equation by cross multiplication, we get
$\frac{x}{1-1}=\frac{-y}{1-1}=\frac{z}{1-1}= k\text{(say)} \implies x=y=z=0$. Therefore, the eigen vector is $\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$.
Now, my question is why the eigen vector turns out to be zero here? The definition of the eigen vector itself says that $Av=\lambda v$, where $\lambda$ is an scalar called eigen value and {\bf non-zero} vector $v$ is called eigen vector corresponding to $\lambda$. But i found some literature, where they seemingly consider zero vector also as an eigen value. Please clearify me where did i go wrong? Though similar questions might be asked in this forum already but my problem couln't be fixed by those problems yet.

Comment: The expressions $x/(1-1)$ etc. that you’ve come up with are undefined, so you can’t draw any conclusions about the values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ from them.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is $x+y+z=0$
For example $(2,-1,-1)$ works as an eigenvector for eigenvalue $2$ 
You can find another one as well such as $(1,1,-2)$

Answer (score 1):

no! actually we have one single equation, so arbitrarily take two values and then find one

For, take $y=t$ and $z=k$ to see the eigenspace corresponding to $2$ is $$\Bigg\{t \begin{pmatrix} -1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}+k \begin{pmatrix} -1\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}: k,t \in \Bbb{R}\Bigg\}$$

Answer (score 0):

The eigenspace$E_2$ for the eigenvalue $2$ has equation $\; x+yz=0$, hence it is isomorphic to $K^2$ ($K$ being the base field) by the isomorphism
\begin{align}
K^2&\longrightarrow E_2\\
(x,y)&\longmapsto (x,y,-x-y)
\end{align}
The image by this isomorphism of the canonical basis of $K^2$: $\;(1,0,-1)$ and $(0,1,-1)$,  is a basis of the eigenspace.